# Invalid Root In Registry Key in reading IExplorer VBA

Tags: vba, registry

I have a code that tries to run an IExplorer that would load a google map. Anyways, It bugs everytime it tries to run the code where it reads the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\" & "App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE\`
with the error: Invalid Root in registry key
[image]

```
Dim obj_FSO As Object
Dim obj_Shell As Object
Dim str_IEVersion As String
Dim StrArray() As String
Dim iVersion As Integer

Set obj_FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set obj_Shell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")

str_IEVersion = obj_FSO.GetFileVersion(obj_Shell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\" & "App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE\"))
```

Comment: HKLM is just a abreviation for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, you need to use the real name.

Comment: @VincentG I'm running this on a Windows 10 and 64 bit and HKLM is fine. However, I'll get back to you as I would let a colleague test this in their computers where it generated the said error.

Comment: Hi @VincentG We still got an error despite the spelled out HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. Is there a way to detect that path programatically so we won't have to change the path each time?

Comment: Your code should work. Did you check with the Registry editor if the key exists on your colleague's computer?

Comment: I still haven't verified but it looks like it's the problem. I'm actually looking for a code to loop through an HKLM directory and improvise it so that the path will be flexible. I think I found one. I'll post my solution should I get successful. Thanks @VincentG